# Stream response Vertx with webclient

Tags: vert.x, vert.x-webclient

I am using **vertx** 3.7.1 and using it's webclient I want to download document(/'s) from an API.

I have to read the document as stream of bytes (just like the way apache http client gives the caller an `inputstream` using which we can read byte by byte or buffer of bytes), thought to leverage `Buffer` class in **vertx** stack however while debugging I found `Buffer` reads(buffers by design) all bytes from the underlying connection and keeps it ready and it doesnt seems to be doing streaming.

Is there a way to get hold of `inputstream` for streaming document bytes or did i misunderstood netty's buffer implementation in vertx.
I cannot change the tech stack, it has to be Vertx.

Any thoughts please...